# Accessing image pixels; comparision of MatIterator_<> and Mat::at operator

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to compare the running time to scan images pixels for a grayscale image in OpenCV version 3.0. I have already gone through the OpenCV documentation [how_to_scan_images](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html)

I understand that `cv::convertTo` would be the fastest at because of various optimizations. I also understand that the `cpointer` style method would be the second best. However, i am surprised at the difference between the `MatIterator` (method3) and `Mat::at` operator (method 2). The documentation [how_to_scan_images](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html) mentions that the `MatIterator` should be comparatively faster than the `Mat::at<>` operator but the result that i have received is different.
Am i missing something here? Is this result expected?
At the initial stages of algorithm development i would like to use the MatIterator because of its similarity to STL iterator and is generally considered a safer way.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I am using OpenCV 3.0 on Ubuntu. The output shown below is approximately consistent within +- 0.5 ms for multiple runs.

In the code below I am effectively calculating (`newImage = alpha*oldImage +beta` ) and comparing the performance of the following methods

Method1: using `cv:: convertTo` , Time in ms = 0.709923

Method2: using `img.at<uchar>(row,col)`, Time in ms = 5.09625

Method3: using `MatIterator_<uchar> it`, Time in ms = 18.277

Method4: `cpointer uchar * p = img.ptr<uchar>(row)`, Time in ms =  3.49983

Method5: `cpointer uchar * src = img.data`, Time in ms = 3.28267

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
string imgname("baboon.jpg");
if (argc>1)
    imgname = argv[1];
Mat im = imread(imgname.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR);
if (im.empty())
{ cout<<" Invalid image read, imgname =argv[1] = "<<imgname<<endl; 
    return -1;
}
Mat img;
cvtColor(im, img,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
// method 1: using convertTo
Mat img1;
double alpha =1, beta =50;
double t = (double)(getTickCount());
img.convertTo(img1, img.type(),alpha, beta);    
t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
cout<<"Method 1: using convertTo, Time elasped in ms = "<<t*1000<<endl;
namedWindow("img1", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("img1", img1);
// Method2: using img.at<>(row, col) index
 Mat img2 = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
t = (double)(getTickCount());
 for (int row=0; row<img.rows; row++)
{ for (int col =0; col<img.cols; col++)
  { img2.at<uchar>(row,col) = (saturate_cast<uchar>) (alpha*img.at<uchar>   (row,col) + beta);
    }
}
t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
cout<<"Method2: using img.at<uchar>(row,col), Time in ms = "<<t*1000<<endl;

//Method3: using Matiterator for each image point
Mat img3 = Mat::zeros(img.size(),img.type());
t = (double)(getTickCount());
MatIterator_<uchar> it, itDest, end;
    itDest= img3.begin<uchar>(); end =img.end<uchar>();
for (it = img.begin<uchar>(); it!= end; it++,itDest++)
{ *itDest = (saturate_cast<uchar>)((*it)*alpha + beta);
}
t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
cout<<"Method3: using MatIterator_<uchar> it, Time in ms = "<<t*1000<<endl;
//Method4: using c-style pointer, char * p = img.ptr<uchar>(rowNum)
 Mat img4 = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
t = (double)(getTickCount());
for (int row =0; row<img.rows; row++)
{ uchar * srcPtr = img.ptr<uchar>(row);
   uchar * destPtr = img4.ptr<uchar>(row); 
 for (int col =0; col<img.cols; col++)
 { destPtr[col] = (saturate_cast<uchar>) (alpha* srcPtr[col] + beta);
 }
}
t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
cout<<"Method4: cpointer uchar * p = img.ptr<uchar>(row), Time in ms =  "<<t*1000<<endl;

// method 5: using the address given by img.data() and iterating untill the end
Mat img5 = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
t = (double)(getTickCount());
uchar * src = img.data;
uchar * dest =img5.data;
for (int i=0; i<img.rows*img.cols; i++)
    *(dest++) = (saturate_cast<uchar>)(alpha * (*(src++)) + beta);
t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
cout<<"Method5: cpointer uchar * src = img.data, Time in ms =  "<<t*1000<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: There are overloaded operators available too `img6 = alpha*img5 + beta/255` and `cvLUT()` both of which will be very fast.

Comment: I am aware of LUT snd the * method as well. I was more surprised at the difference in speed between "MatIterator" and "at" operator? Is img.at  supposed to be faster than "MatIterator" ? The opencv documemtation mentions otherwise.

Comment: After digging on my own here is my 
**conclusion** : 
    Image scanning methods comparison based upon performance(highest to lowest)  
1) Use library function whenever possible.  
2) Prefer C pointer for faster scan(one can use img.data() for few ms)  3) img.at<> is the next best 4) MatIterator is the least fast.  

*Only in release mode 'Mat::at' is faster than 'MatIterator'.*   MatIterator brings the safety factor with additional checks. However, in debug mode 'MatIterator' is faster than "Mat::at" operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging on my own here is my **conclusion** : 
Image scanning methods comparison based upon performance(highest to lowest)

1. Use library function whenever possible.
2. Prefer C pointer for faster scan(one can use img.data() for few ms gain but be careful!)
3. img.at<> is the next best
4. MatIterator is the least fast.

**Only in release mode 'Mat::at' is faster than 'MatIterator'**. MatIterator brings the safety factor with additional checks. However, in debug mode 'MatIterator' is faster than "Mat::at" operator